# Closing one bootstrap modal and opening another one immediately causes scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals. When I close one and open the other right after, I have scrolling issues. Instead of scrolling in the modal, the content behind it gets scrolled. To solve this, I did the following:

```
$('#firstModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#secondModal').modal();
    $('#firstModal').off('hidden.bs.modal');
});
$('#firstModal').modal('hide');
```

I was wondering, is there a more elegant solution that does not involve using the event listener?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `modal-open` class has not been removed by the time you show the second modal. Therefore, as soon as it is added (by opening the second modal) it is removed because the first one finished closing. You can work around this with the following code:

```
$('#firstModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#secondModal').modal();
  });
});
```